# Deslogar outro usuario django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Bom Dia
Fiz um controle de sessões de usuário através do login e do logout:
No login antes de logar ele faz um insert na minha tabela:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios_sessoes (usuario, datahorainicio) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (str(username),timezone.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')))
```

e no logout faz update:

```
  cursor.execute("""select id
                  from usuarios_sessoes
                  where usuario='"""+str(request.user)+"""'
                  order by datahorainicio desc limit 1""")
    id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Com isso tenho meu controle de sessões, mas o que preciso é que um superusuario, consiga deslogar um usuário qualquer, não encontrei uma solução para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Django Qsessions](https://github.com/QueraTeam/django-qsessions)

Exemplo da documentação (README, no repositório):

Logout a user:

```
for session in user.session_set.all():
    session.delete()
```

O Exemplo não mostra de onde vem a variavel `user`, mas vc poderia fazer:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='nomeususario')
```

**Obs.**
A própria documentação menciona que [django-user-sessions](https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions) (outro pacote django) tem as mesmas funcionalidades.